# Save node modules into USB

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Trying to back up my computer, have lots of node modules that cannot fit onto the USB. Is there an easier way to back up node modules? Or do I just have to write a checklist of what modules I used in which project?

I tried deleting all the folders and leaving the package.json/package-lock.json files but when I run npm install (expecting npm to read the package files) it just rewrites the package files and installs nothing.

Comment: What folders? You shouldn't delete **all** the folders. You should delete only **one** folder - `node_modules` (and whatever it contains)

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to backup node_modules? you can just backup the project without the node_modules and then re-install the dependencies via `npm install`, ensure to backup properly the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files